# TortoiseGit - как убрать из-под контроля версий файлы в папке?

Tags: c++, git, github, tortoise-git

Есть папка с файлами, файлы помечены красными крестами. Цитата из руководства:

> This icon shows you that some files or folders inside the current folder have  been scheduled to be deleted from version control or a file under version control  is missing in a folder.

Что означает "запланированы к удалению"? Когда они удалятся из-под контроля? На следущем коммите? Коммит сделал, иконка не поменялась. Как их удалить из-под контроля вручную?

Comment: это значит, что файлы Вы удалили и гит хочет, что бы ему об этом явно сказали. Когда будете коммитить, нужно добавить эти файлы (как бы это странно не звучало). Если делаете это в консоли, то нужно `git add -u && git commit -m "message"`.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос снят.

Comment: @ИльяИванов, раз «вопрос снят», то удалите его, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пока разбираюсь, как удалить, как разберусь - это сделаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, может, не стоит удалять вопрос, а лучше попросить ув-мого KoVadim перенести сообщение из комментариев в ответы? Может, другие пользователи столкнутся с этой же проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, попросить-то можно. я сам неоднократно просил KoVadim-а о подобном. но, увы, всегда безуспешно. // если у вас есть желание, опубликуйте ответ, сделав его общим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментария KoVadim:

Это значит, что файлы Вы удалили, и Git хочет, чтобы ему об этом явно сказали. Когда будете коммитить, нужно добавить данные файлы (как бы странно это не звучало). Если работаете в консоли, то нужно ввести `git add -u && git commit -m "message"`.